# Unable to create buy it now listing instead of auction using eBay API

Tags: php, ebay-api

I am using the following code from `eBay API` to create new listings in eBay.

The code, however, only creates `auction` type listings.
I tried not setting start price and only added buy now price, but the result was still an `auction` listing.

How can I create `buy it now` items/listings instead?

Here is my PHP code for calling the API's `AddItem` endpoint:

```
<?php
/********************************************
addItem.php

Uses eBay Trading API to list an item under
a seller's account.

********************************************/

// include our Trading API constants
require_once 'tradingConstants.php';

// check if posted
if (!empty($_POST)) {

// grab our posted keywords and call helper function
// TODO: check if need urlencode
$title = $_POST['title'];
$categoryID = $_POST['categoryID'];
$startPrice = $_POST['startPrice'];
$pictureURL = $_POST['pictureURL'];
$description = $_POST['description'];

// call the getAddItem function to make AddItem call
  $response = getAddItem($title, $categoryID, $startPrice, $pictureURL, $description);

}

// Function to call the Trading API AddItem
function getAddItem($addTitle, $addCatID, $addSPrice, $addPicture, $addDesc) {

/* Sample XML Request Block for minimum AddItem request
see ... for sample XML block given length*/

// Create unique id for adding item to prevent duplicate adds
$uuid = md5(uniqid());

// create the XML request
$xmlRequest = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
$xmlRequest .= "<AddItemRequest xmlns=\"urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents\">";
$xmlRequest .= "<ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Item>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Title>" . $addTitle . "</Title>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Description>" . $addDesc . "</Description>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PrimaryCategory>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<CategoryID>" . $addCatID . "</CategoryID>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</PrimaryCategory>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<StartPrice>" . $addSPrice . "</StartPrice>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ConditionID>1000</ConditionID>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<CategoryMappingAllowed>true</CategoryMappingAllowed>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<BuyItNowPrice currencyID=\"USD\">" . $addSPrice . "</BuyItNowPrice>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Country>US</Country>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Currency>USD</Currency>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<DispatchTimeMax>3</DispatchTimeMax>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ListingDuration>Days_7</ListingDuration>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ListingType>FixedPriceItem</ListingType>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PaymentMethods>PayPal</PaymentMethods>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PayPalEmailAddress>@gmail.com</PayPalEmailAddress>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PictureDetails>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PictureURL>" . $addPicture . "</PictureURL>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</PictureDetails>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<PostalCode>05485</PostalCode>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Quantity>1</Quantity>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ReturnPolicy>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ReturnsAcceptedOption>ReturnsAccepted</ReturnsAcceptedOption>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<RefundOption>MoneyBack</RefundOption>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ReturnsWithinOption>Days_30</ReturnsWithinOption>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Description>" . $addDesc . "</Description>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingCostPaidByOption>Buyer</ShippingCostPaidByOption>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</ReturnPolicy>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingDetails>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingType>Flat</ShippingType>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServiceOptions>";
$xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServicePriority>1</ShippingServicePriority>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingService>USPSMedia</ShippingService>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<ShippingServiceCost>2.50</ShippingServiceCost>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</ShippingServiceOptions>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</ShippingDetails>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<Site>US</Site>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<UUID>" . $uuid . "</UUID>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</Item>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<RequesterCredentials>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<eBayAuthToken>" . AUTH_TOKEN . "</eBayAuthToken>";
  $xmlRequest .= "</RequesterCredentials>";
  $xmlRequest .= "<WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>";
$xmlRequest .= "</AddItemRequest>";

// define our header array for the Trading API call
// notice different headers from shopping API and SITE_ID changes to SITEID
$headers = array(
'X-EBAY-API-SITEID:'.SITEID,
'X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:AddItem',
'X-EBAY-API-REQUEST-ENCODING:'.RESPONSE_ENCODING,
'X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:' . API_COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL,
'X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:' . API_DEV_NAME,
'X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:' . API_APP_NAME,
'X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:' . API_CERT_NAME,
'Content-Type: text/xml;charset=utf-8'
);

// initialize our curl session
$session = curl_init(API_URL);

// set our curl options with the XML request
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xmlRequest);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// execute the curl request
$responseXML = curl_exec($session);

// close the curl session
curl_close($session);

// return the response XML
return $responseXML;
}
?>
```

Comment: tried not setting a start price in the xml and submitting it with only a buy it now price ?

Comment: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ebay

Comment: @Dave, i just did that and for some strange reason it still creates an auction type listing!

Comment: @Smandoli, what am I suppose to do with that?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the ebay api but have you checked it to see if there's a specific additional xml tag you need to pass in to define it as a buy it now only (can you even create buy it now only without having an auction option on the main ebay web interface its self?)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is more suitable for webapps.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

its because you are using the wrong API call, if you want to create buy it now (only) items you should use the "AddFixedPriceItem" Call

you can play around with this call here: https://ebay-sdk.intradesys.com/s/b53b3a3d6ab90ce0268229151c9bde11 it should use nearly the same inputs that you already have.

if you want to create a auction item with buy it now option you can keep calling addItem but you will need to add the "BuyItNowPrice" Object within the ItemObject